# How to update xml file parameter using .bat file?

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am new to windows batch programming.

I have the below XML file

```
<itp:params>
  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
  <itp:param name="persid">PERSID__</itp:param>
  <itp:param name="attmnt">ATTMNTID__</itp:param>
</itp:params>
```

Now I have to replace the parameter PERSID__ & ATTMNTID__ using batch file.

I am able to update the PERSID__ using the following code

```
set _ATTMNTID=%1
set _PERSID=%2
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "search=PERSID__"
set "replace=%_PERSID%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%_XML_TPL%) DO (
   set line=%%a
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   >> %_TEMP_FILE% echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
   endlocal
)
```

But struggling to update the second param ATTMNTID__.

Comment: Being that we don't know what you're replacing the strings with and have no idea from your snippet if your XML file is encoded as UTF-16 or UTF-8, a pure batch file solution may be unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q48861626.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

set _ATTMNTID=%1
set _PERSID=%2
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "search=PERSID__"
set "replace=%_PERSID%"
SET "SEARCH2=ATTMNTID__"
SET "REPLACE2=%_ATTMNTID%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%filename1%) DO (
   set line=%%a
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   SET "line=!line:%search2%=%replace2%!"
   ECHO !line:%search%=%replace%!
   endlocal
)>> %outfile%


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q48861626.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Simply cascade the substitutions.

Note the use of quotes in `set` commands to ensure that trailing spaces on the line are not included in the data assigned.

Note the placement of the redirection to the output file.  It gathers all `echo` output from the `code block` and redirects to the file, so `>` could be used here in place of `>>` to create a new file if desired.

Comment: Thank you very much Magoo for your help.You suggested code is working fine for my requirement.